# Parallelism setting when running Chutzpah under a TFS build

Tags: chutzpah

We have our TFS (2013) build configured to run javascript qunit tests under Chutzpah (4.0.3) by following [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx). By default, Chutzpah is executing with a parallelism set to 2 (according to the chutzpah.log generated during a build).

Is there a way to adjust the amount of parallelism?  I'd like to set it to 1 to help diagnose some random failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property in the .runsettings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
 <ChutzpahAdapterSettings>
   <MaxDegreeOfParallelism>2</MaxDegreeOfParallelism>
 </ChutzpahAdapterSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

See https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Running-Unit-Tests-in-a-TFS-Build

Comment: I see what you did there. :) Thanks, just what I was looking for!